# Get stored Date from MySQL without converting it into GMT format?

Tags: mysql, node.js, server, mysqljs

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | date                | title   | seconds |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|  1 |      16 | 2020-05-22 23:23:55 |  value  |      35 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

When fetching data with node server this data transforms into:

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    user_id: 16,
    date: 2020-05-22T20:23:55.000Z,
    title: 'value',
    seconds: 35
  }
]
```

Is there any way to get the same data, which stored in database without creating one more column for timezone?
Using **mysqljs** package for node.

Comment: If you are using MySQL please untag SQL Server.

Comment: Was it stored with a time zone?

Comment: From frontend I'm sending Unix Timestamp, then saving it in date field FROM_UNIXTIME(<seconds>)
date field is DATETIME type for that matter

Comment: let config = {
    // ...
    timezone: 'UTC',
}

Try this..

https://medium.com/@magnusjt/gotcha-timezones-in-nodejs-and-mysql-b39e418c9d3